# Plist email attachment disappearing

Tags: objective-c, email, xcode5

I am a just getting started with Xcode and trying to finish my first app, the final part is to email the Plist, I have used this save path:

```
- (NSString *)dataFilePath6 {
    NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
    return [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"data6.plist"];
```

and this attach method:

```
NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"data6" ofType:@"plist"];
NSData *myData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:path];
[mc addAttachmentData:myData mimeType:@"application/xml" fileName:@"data6.plist"];
```

When I run the app on my iPad, the file shows as an attachment and the email sends, but when I receive the email there is no attachment.

Basically I just needed to get the data the user had imputed into the `UITextField`s.

Comment: I have made some changes, I am now creating a CSV file, but have the same problem, when the email arrives there is no attachment

Comment: NSString *docPath =[NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES)
                        objectAtIndex:0];
    
    NSString *nSteps=[docPath stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"NextSteps.csv"];
    
    if ([[NSFileManager defaultManager] fileExistsAtPath:nSteps]) {
        NSFileHandle *fileHandle = [NSFileHandle fileHandleForReadingAtPath:nSteps];
        
        NSString *nStepsResults=[[NSString alloc]initWithData:[fileHandle availableData] encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
        [fileHandle closeFile];
        self.resultView.text=nStepsResults;

Comment: I have found someone having the same problem and someone gave this as a solution   MFMailComposeViewController *mailer = [[MFMailComposeViewController alloc] init];
mailer.mailComposeDelegate = self;
[mailer setSubject:@"CSV File"];

NSData *myData = [text dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];    
[mailer addAttachmentData:myData mimeType:@"text/cvs" fileName:@"FileName"];

[self presentModalViewController:mailer animated:YES];  they say "Text" is the string, which string are they referring too?

Comment: After lots of changes and internet surfing I solved the problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
- (IBAction)EmailCSVdata:(id)sender {

    //sqlite3

    NSArray *pathssqlite = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);

    NSString *fileName = @"SVR.sql";
    NSString *documentsDirectory2 = [pathssqlite objectAtIndex:0];




    NSString *csvPathwithFileName = [documentsDirectory2 stringByAppendingPathComponent:fileName];
    NSData *csvData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:csvPathwithFileName];


    MFMailComposeViewController *controller2 = [[MFMailComposeViewController alloc] init];
    controller2.mailComposeDelegate = self;
    [controller2 setSubject:@"Store Visit SQL DB..."];
    [controller2 setMessageBody:@"Store Visit SQL DB For V3.5 is here.." isHTML:YES];
    NSArray *toRecipents = [NSArray arrayWithObject:@"XXX@.com"];
    [controller2 setToRecipients:toRecipents];

    //sqlite3

    [controller2 addAttachmentData:csvData mimeType:@"application/x-sqlite3" fileName:@"SVR.sql"];



    [self presentViewController:controller2 animated:YES completion:NULL];

}
```

Comment: I did finally solve my problem with the above code & changed to an Sqlite export